# How can i replace green box into in yellow box and yellow box into in green box ? So is there any css property ? help out

Tags: javascript, html, css, alignment, box

https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/884349/?ref=app

This is code in sololearn playground.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body, don't just rely on a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 0):

In your css replace the color property for the left and right sections.

Should be as follows:

```
  #left-panel {
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100px;
  }

  #right-section {
    background-color: green;
    height: 500px;
  }
```

Comment: But content gonna wrong bcoz in left-panel have their own content and same as right-section.